# TextChanged event not being triggered with UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 textboxes: txtSKU1 and txtDescription1. I want the user put text into txtSKU1, then hit tab and have the txtSKU1_TextChanged event fire, which will auto populate txtDescription1. I'm trying to avoid using a postback. From my understanding, the TextChanged event fires after it loses focus, so I assumed the UpdatePanel I used below would work but nothing happens until I do a trigger a postback. Any ideas?

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSKU1" runat="server" width="100%" BorderColor="#dddddd" OnTextChanged="txtSKU1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription1" runat="server" width="100%" BorderColor="#dddddd"></asp:TextBox>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtSKU1" EventName="TextChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
```

Comment: You could try doing this with javascript

Comment: I'm open to that, but I'm curious as to why the above code does not work. I've used UpdatePanel's before that were trigger with a click and it worked, but I cannot figure out why TextChanged won't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the UpdatePanel, it's just that the `TextChanged` event is one that only fires during a postback that's been triggered by something else.

To get `TextChanged` to trigger the postback, set its `AutPostBack` attribute:

```
OnTextChanged="txtSKU1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
```

Comment: Is it not possible to fire `TextChanged` without a postback? I've used a link label's click event to clear a textbox's text using an `Update Panel` which didn't trigger a postback. I'm trying do something like the user to enter a SKU, hit tab, then the `TextChange` event fires with no postback

Comment: No, it's not. (Try it, in a simple webform.) But I'm not saying you have to do a full postback. I'm referring to any postback, including the postback that occurs during the [partial page rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386573(v=vs.100).aspx) an UpdatePanel does.